# DRYing out my action creators

Tags: javascript, ajax, react.js, promise, redux

I've created a private function called `_successResponse` to handle successful responses from my promise.

The challenge was passing the dispatch function to the `_successResponse` which is being passed to the `.then` method as a callback.

I accomplished this by currying using `.bind`. I would love to get feedback on this approach.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { 
        AUTH_USER,
        AUTH_ERROR,
        UNAUTH_USER,
        FETCH_MESSAGE
    } from './types';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3090';

export function signinUser({ email, password }){
    return function(dispatch){
        // Submit email/password to server
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, { email, password })
            .then(_successResponse.bind(null, dispatch))
            .catch(() => {dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'))})
    }
}

export function signupUser({email, password}){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signup`, { email, password })
            .then(_successResponse.bind(null, dispatch))
            .catch(response => {dispatch(authError(response.response.data.error))});
    }
}

export function authError(error){
    return {
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
        payload: error
    }
}

export function signoutUser(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token');

    return { type: UNAUTH_USER }
}

export function fetchMessage(){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get(ROOT_URL, {
            headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }
        })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_MESSAGE,
                    payload: response.data.message
                })
            });
    }
}

// Private functions
function _successResponse(dispatch, response){
        // If request is valid...
        // - Update state to indicate user is authenticated
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        // - Save the JWT token
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        // - redirect to the route '/feature'
        browserHistory.push('/feature');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Currying?

[image: 1]

[Photo hosted via unsplash, taken by Monika Grabkowska](https://unsplash.com/@moniqa?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=photographer-credit&utm_content=creditBadge)

Yes you used [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the callback function as the first argument to the private function, and this is a good approach to avoid excess functions and reduce the number of lines. While the concept is similar, what this code uses is actually [**Partial Application**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions). Read more about the differences in [this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-currying-vs-partial-application-4db5b2442be8#169e).

---

The first couple functions appear to catch errors, but `fetchMessage()` doesn't appear to. Maybe you have updated it since you posted it but if not, I would suggest adding error handling there too.

---

You could consider using `async` and `await` to reduce the `.then()` callbacks.